# Transition avplayer to fullscreen from embedded view

Tags: ios

I am currently displaying a video embedded in a view. On tap of this video I need to present it in full screen just like how App Store does it.

Right now I am using `AVPlayer` to embed in the view with a `AVPlayerLayer`. When I detect a tap on this embedded player, I am creating a `AVPlayerViewController` and setting its player object with the player currently embedded, but still I can notice a delay of 3~4 seconds until the player in fullscreen starts playing. How can I make this transition smooth ?